# Calling weather API in Restplus

Tags: python, flask, api-design, flask-restplus

I'm trying to figure out how can I call an API using Flask-Restplus (using API key, as it always was possible - let's say the easiest example is weather). I know how I can do it in Flask, but have no idea how can I do it in Restplus. There are tons of documentations, but mostly about working with local database. If you can point me to the correct direction, I'd appreciate that very much.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#argument-parsing

Comment: Sorry, but I read it already and didn't get. Can you maybe explain more or provide live example of using please?

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulate question correctly. What I need to do is call weather API from Restplus.